# Convert a Recursive Query to parameterized query

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

What is the best approach to parameterize a recursive query?

As an example, let's take the following query: (taken from [postgresqltutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/)):

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
    SELECT
        employee_id,
        manager_id,
        full_name
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE
        employee_id = 2
    UNION
        SELECT
            e.employee_id,
            e.manager_id,
            e.full_name
        FROM
            employees e
        INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.employee_id = e.manager_id
) 
SELECT *
FROM subordinates;
```

How could I modify it to allowed me to pass **employee_id** as a parameter or clause of my query?

I found a solution where I put this query in a function that receives **employee_id** as parameter and return a table (with employee_id, manager_id, full_name columns), but I'm not sure if this is a good/elegant solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_subordinates(employee_id_param INT)
RETURNS TABLE (
    employee_id INT,
    full_name VARCHAR,
    manager_id INT) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY

    WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
    SELECT
        employee_id,
        manager_id,
        full_name
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE
        employee_id = employee_id_param
    UNION
        SELECT
            e.employee_id,
            e.manager_id,
            e.full_name
        FROM
            employees e
        INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.employee_id = e.manager_id
) 
SELECT *
FROM subordinates;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'No found %.', $1;
END IF;

RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Could I get the same result using a VIEW where **employee_id** could be passed as a clause or something like that?

Any suggestion will really appreciated.

Comment: Offtopic: Are you sure about the EXCEPTION? Not finding any result is imho not an exception, it's normal behaviour for a database when there is no data that matches your request.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, it really depends the case. It is just a bit of business logic inside this function. But I agree with you that in the majority of the cases it should not be an exception.

Comment: Views can't have parameters. Using a function is the only option you have here as far as I can tell.

Comment: BTW: the function could be made `LANGUAGE sql;`

Comment: You do it the same way you would if it were not recursive.

Comment: @wildplasser: You can't use exceptions when using LANGUAGE SQL. Not that I would recommend an exception for this, it's not an error.